# Acess scripts in external snakemake directory without defining absolute path

Tags: snakemake

My end goal is to host a snakemake workflow on a GitHub repo that can be accessed as a snakemake module. I'm testing locally before I host it, but I'm running into an issue. I cannot access the scripts in the snakemake module directory. It looks locally in the current snakemake directory for the scripts, which I obviously cannot move locally if my end goal is to host the module remotely.

I don't see this problem when accessing Conda environments in the remote directory. Is there a way to mimic this behavior for a scripts directory? I would be open to an absolute path reference if it can be applied to access a remote script directory. Here's a dummy example reproducing the error:

Snakemake version: 6.0.5

Tree structure:

```sh
.
├── external_module
│   ├── scripts
│   │   ├── argparse
│   │   └── print.py
│   └── Snakefile
└── Snakefile
```

Local snakefile:

```
module remote_module:
    snakefile: "external_module/Snakefile"

use rule * from remote_module

use rule foo from remote_module with:
    input:
        "complete.txt"
```

External Snakefile:

```
rule foo:
    input:
        "complete.txt"

rule bar:
    output:
        touch(temp("complete.txt"))
    shell:
        "scripts/print.py -i foo"
```

print.py

```py
import argparse

def get_parser():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
        description='dummy snakemake function',
        formatter_class=argparse.ArgumentDefaultsHelpFormatter)

    parser.add_argument("-i", default=None,
                        help="item to be printed")
    
    return parser

def main():
    args = get_parser().parse_args()
    print(args.i)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Snakemake pipeline execution

```
(base) bobby@SongBird:~/remote_snakemake_test$ snakemake --cores 4
Building DAG of jobs...
Using shell: /usr/bin/bash
Provided cores: 4
Rules claiming more threads will be scaled down.
Job counts:
        count   jobs
        1       bar
        1       foo
        2

[Fri Mar 26 10:12:50 2021]
rule bar:
    output: complete.txt
    jobid: 1

/usr/bin/bash: scripts/print.py: No such file or directory
[Fri Mar 26 10:12:50 2021]
Error in rule bar:
    jobid: 1
    output: complete.txt
    shell:
        scripts/print.py -i foo
        (one of the commands exited with non-zero exit code; note that snakemake uses bash strict mode!)

Shutting down, this might take some time.
Exiting because a job execution failed. Look above for error message
Complete log: /home/bobby/remote_snakemake_test/.snakemake/log/2021-03-26T101250.118440.snakemake.log
```

Any insight would be very appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I just run into this issue. In my case I define the custom scripts in the params. What solution did you follow at the end?

Answer (score 1):

I'm strugglig with modules and associated scripts as well. AFAIK the 'shell' entry does *NOT* keep track of the external path, whereas the 'script' entry does. So consider an external module with the following rules:

```
rule foo_shell:
  ...
  shell:
    "script/somescript -a somearg ..."

rule foo_script:
  ...
  script:
    "scripts/somescript_without_arguments.py"
```

Rule foo_shell will look for the script `somescript` in the subdir scripts relative to the main (local) Snakefile, which in your example obviously doesn't exist. Rule foo_script will look for the script `somescript_without_arguments.py` in the scripts directory in the directory containing the remote Snakefile, ie in your external_module/scripts directory.
Scripts called via the scripts entry cannot be called using arguments, but they instead have access to a variable 'snakemake', see [the docs](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/rules.html#external-scripts). Also, only a few languages are possible, eg python, R, ...

I made some changes to your example which worked for me:

local/main Snakefile:

```
module remote_module:
    snakefile: "external_module/Snakefile"
    config: config

use rule * from remote_module

use rule foo from remote_module with:
    input:
        "complete.txt"
```

external_module/Snakefile:

```
rule foo:
    input:
        "complete.txt"

rule bar:
    output:
        touch(temp("complete.txt"))
    params:
      i="foo2"
    script:
        "scripts/print2.py"
```

external_module/scripts/print2.py (ugly, but informative :-) )

```
print(snakemake.params["i"])
```

Something that confuses me is that it seems that in the script used in the external module additional, external, python or R scripts can be used by importing (python) or sourcing (R) them in the called script. The following external python script works just fine, assuming script1.py and script2.py are both in the scripts directory in the external module:

```
# script1.py
import script2

...
```

But so far I have not been able to execute a bash script from, eg, a running python script. Something like `subprocess.run("remote_module_script.sh","arg")` again looks for the bash script relative to the directory which contains the main, local snakefile. It seems there is no way to run bash scripts in remote modules, except using methods explained in Troy's answer. As I want to be able to use modules completely external to the current filesystem (eg directly from github) this option doesn't work for me.

I hope I'm wrong wrt to bash scripts and somebody will explain better how external modules and external (bash) scripts actually do work.

Answer (score 0):

Modules are new to me, so this may not be the best way.  The behavior seems slightly buggy, but this works for now...

It looks like you can access the base directory of the workflow, `.`, with `workflow.basedir` and the external directory, `external_module`, with `workflow.current_basedir` within `external_module/Snakefile`.  However, it seems like you can't use those functions in the rule while it is executed in a module.  If you save it as a variable, you can use it later, but only if the variable is also defined in the main Snakefile.

This works:

```py
# Snakefile
module remote_module:
    snakefile: "external_module/Snakefile"

use rule * from remote_module

my_basedir = "DOESN'T MATTER"
use rule foo from remote_module with:
    input:
        "complete.txt"

# external_module/Snakefile
my_basedir = workflow.current_basedir

rule foo:
    input:
        "complete.txt"

rule bar:
    output:
        touch(temp("complete.txt"))
    shell:
        "{my_basedir}/scripts/print.py -i foo"
```

`my_basedir` will have the value of the correct directory.  But, if you remove the  assignment of `my_basedir` in the top level Snakefile, the variable won't be available, though clearly the value itself isn't used.  Seems like a bug that will get patched eventually, so it's probably safer to set it to `workflow.basedir + '/external_module'`.

I'll also note that if you run the workflow in a different working directory the relative path to print.py will break in the original example.  It may be safer, and more sane, to set that path as a config variable and set it correctly in your main Snakefile, like this:

```py
# Snakefile
config['my_basedir'] = workflow.current_basedir + '/external_module'
module remote_module:
    snakefile: "external_module/Snakefile"

use rule * from remote_module

use rule foo from remote_module with:
    input:
        "complete.txt"

# external_module/Snakefile
rule foo:
    input:
        "complete.txt"

rule bar:
    output:
        touch(temp("complete.txt"))
    shell:
        "{config[my_basedir]}/scripts/print.py -i foo"
```

Thanks for the good toy example!

Comment: Note that you can also use an f-string in your command: `f"{workflow.current_basedir}/scripts/print.py -i foo"`